# How to fix the random numbers generated by Excel rand()

Tags: excel, random

I am using =rand() to generate a lot of random number. Everytime, I make some changes in the file, it will generate a whole new set of numbers. I want to keep the numbers random, but keep them fixed everytime. How to do that?

Comment: Turn off auto-calculation of formulas.

Comment: copy what numbers you got and paste values only

Answer (score 3):

`Rand()` is a volatile funciton. This means that it is recalculated every time Excel recalculates. Pretty much you have three options (2 mentioned in the comments):

- set the calculations to manual (this is dangerous, you may forget it later);
- remove the formula and save the values (this will work quite ok);
- make a `User Defined Function`, which does exactly the same and is non-volatile:

---

```
Public Function RandNotUpdate() As Double
    RandNotUpdate = Rnd
End Function
```